# What specifications should be used when creating a native token logo?

Tags: token

What specifications should be used when creating a native token logo (e.g. dpi, pixel dimensions, size, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard or specification you need to follow for creating a native token logo. You should use the same width and height if you want your token logo to be correctly displayed in wallets, though.

You can find an example of dimensions that will work properly here: https://cardano.org/brand-assets